# Python combine partially the same Array

Tags: python

I've a 2D array and would like to combine partially similar items.

```
[
[Red,Blue,Yellow,5]
[Red,Blue,Yellow,10]
[Red,Blue,Green,5]
[Red,Blue,Green,5]
[Red,Blue,Orange,5]
[Red,Blue,Violet,5]
]
```

I want it to become like this, trimming and creating a unique array

```
[
[Red,Blue,Yellow,15]
[Red,Blue,Green,10]
[Red,Blue,Orange,5]
[Red,Blue,Violet,5]
]
```

Edit1: Here's what i did. I've only the basics and would like to have a better version.

```
newTaskList = []
totalTaskList = []
totalValueList = []
finalTaskList = []

for taskIndex, taskList in enumerate(readTaskList):
    newTaskList = []
    newTaskList.append(taskList[0])
    newTaskList.append(taskList[1])
    newTaskList.append(taskList[2])
    newTaskList.append(taskList[4])


    if(newTaskList not in totalTaskList):
        totalTaskList.append(newTaskList)
        totalValueList.append(float(taskList[3]))

    else:
        for itemIndex, itemList in enumerate(totalTaskList):
            if(itemList[0] == taskList[0] and itemList[1] == taskList[1] and itemList[2] == taskList[2] and itemList[3] == taskList[4]):
                totalValueList[itemIndex] += float(taskList[3])

for taskIndex, task in enumerate(totalTaskList):
    for workType in workTypeList:
        newWorkTypeItem = task[2].replace(" ","_").split("_")
        if len(newWorkTypeItem) > 1:
            task[2] = newWorkTypeItem[0] + " " + newWorkTypeItem[1]

        if(task[1] == workType[0] and task[2] == workType[1]):
            task[2] = workType[2]
            break            
    task.append(totalValueList[taskIndex])
    finalTaskList.append(task)
```

Comment: Show what you've tried already

Comment: Please check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Hint: this could probably be done in one line of code (excepting imports) using *itertools* module.

Comment: I'd create a `defaultdict`, use a tuple of the colors as a key, and iterate through, adding all the values with the same keys together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **collections** Module.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [
['Red','Blue','Yellow',5],
['Red','Blue','Yellow',10],
['Red','Blue','Green',5],
['Red','Blue','Green',5],
['Red','Blue','Orange',5],
['Red','Blue','Violet',5],
]

d = defaultdict(int)
for i in l:
    d[tuple(i[:3])] += i[-1]
print [list(k) + [v] for k,v in d.items()]
```

**Output:**

```
[['Red', 'Blue', 'Orange', 5], ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 15], ['Red', 'Blue', 'Violet', 5], ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 10]]
```

Comment: I knew there's an awesome way in doing it in python and here it is! Thank you so much.

Comment: A thing to mention is that the result wouldn't appear in the same order as the original list but if that is not an issue for your purpose you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict`.

```
result = defaultdict(int)
for col1, col2, col3, value in my_list:
   result[(col1, col2, col3)] += value
result = [list(key) + [value] for key,value in result.items()]
print(result)
```

Output

```
[['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 15], ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 10], ['Red', 'Blue', 'Orange', 5], ['Red', 'Blue', 'Violet', 5]]
```